# Connecting to Navision Web Service using Negotiate authorization

Tags: php, web-services, navision

I have a service running on Navision accessed by url http://navision_ip/NAV/WS/COMPANY/Codeunit/Web_Service

I also have login / password for service.

When I try to open link with Chrome, after entering credentials, I get wsdl.

I also see that Chrome passes Authorization: Negotiate  header.

Other browsers return 401 / 400 instead of wsdl and doesn't show the wsdl.

How do I get wsdl in PHP?

Comment: Ensure that [NTLM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355055.aspx) is activated on the Navision server.  Option is available from NAV 2009...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the authentication to NTLM = true in the CustomSettings.config file.

I found this blog post very useful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from.aspx

and for php:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-php.aspxhttp://blogs.msdn.com/b/freddyk/archive/2010/01/19/connecting-to-nav-web-services-from-php.aspx

Comment: That's similar solution that we took. Asked administrators to change auth method since there's no easy way from PHP to access webservice by using Negotiation.